# change my sql with php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on my first complex project and I got a little problem.

The same as for a picture, the users will upload a csv file, and this file will be stored in MySQL.

example[image]

But after, the users will be able to **change the "status" column, or even delete the data, using the ckeckbox and the dropdown list.
But i have no idea how to do this.**

An example:

When the user change the dropdown list to "Excluir", and click on "Alterar" button, the row is excluded from mysql.

or

When the user select "Cancelado" in dropdown, and click in "Alterar", the status is changed.

Following is the code used:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
  <title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
  </head> 

  <body> 

  <?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
    Choose your file: <br /> 
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form> 
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2"> 
    <label>Selecione o status:</label>
    <select name="changePed">
      <option value="separacao">Em Separação</option>
      <option value="cancelado">Cancelado</option>
      <option value="faturado">Faturado</option>
      <option value="exp">Expedido</option>
      <option value="exc">Ecluir</option>
    </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Alterar">
             </form>
  <?php
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `pedidos`");

  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
  <th>Data de emissão</th>
  <th>EMS</th>
  <th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
  <th>Cliente</th>
  <th>Valor do pedido</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox'></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pedCliente'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['vlr'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need only to filter the actions corresponding them to your queries:

```
        <?php
        switch($_POST['changePed']){
          case 'separacao':
              $sql = 'DO YOUR QUERY';
              break;
        case 'cancelado':
              $sql = 'DO YOUR QUERY';
              break;
        case 'faturado':
              $sql = 'DO YOUR QUERY';
              break;
        case 'exp':
              $sql = 'DO YOUR QUERY';
              break;
        case 'exc':
           //if you want to delete by checkboxes
              $sql = "DELETE FROM pedidos WHERE pedidos.id IN ('" . implode(",", $_POST['checkbox']) ."') "; 
              break;

        }

        if (isset($sql)){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    /* Select queries return a resultset */
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        //do something

        /* free result set */
        $result->close();
    } else {
       die('Error');
    }
        }

        ?>

//Your frontend from checkboxes:
    <?php
      $i = 0;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><input name='checkbox[$i]' type='checkbox'></td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['emissaoPed'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['pedCliente'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['vlr'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
       $i++;
      }
      echo "</table>";
      ?>
```

Comment: Don't write answers using `mysql_query()` or any other deprecated functions.

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I really don't know about this option. But I have one doubt yet. How can I, well, link the selects checkboxes with the query? like,  how I say the ID for the query "DELETE FROM `pedidos` WHERE `pedidos`.`id` = 8"

Comment: Use for instead of while to be more elegant, but each index inside checkbox[] name input and when backend receives by post, only the selected will show! I'll try to draw something for you, an idea.